# Tree manage in ribbon UI

Tags: usability, gui-design, tree, ribbon

I'm implementing ribbon UI in one of my application. It manages some trees so I move all the  options to the ribbon (contextual tabs) but it just doesn't look fluent.

[image: Ribbon UI tree expanding]

[image: Ribbon UI Tree selection]

Is placing tree options like this a good idea?

Comment: I really dont understand this question

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It seems like the different options are more related with each other than that they are unrelated. They all manage "tree operation". In that sense it would make a lot of sense to combine them on just 1 tab. It would take away the need for users to constantly switch between the tabs.

The fact that you have plenty of screen real estate left is also an argument for combining.

Another thing worth mentioning is that your current UI uses terms like "tree" and "children". Unless your tree is a real tree (the thing that grows in forests), and the children of the tree are real children (little grown ups), I strongly recommend you to replace these terms by the terms they actually represent.